# How to mock or bypass Navigator.credentials in E2E test cypress?

Tags: cypress, single-sign-on, navigator, e2e

How do I mock this message when using cypress?
its comes out of

`Navigator.credentials`

[image]

how to pass this authentication when trying to use cypress ? do I need to adjust the app to provide a bypass?

Comment: May I know which url u r trying to access ? Can't u get user password element and try to hardcode password ?

Comment: nop. the whole point is to do authentication with finger print. and it raise the question. how to?